# Match values of 2 case class

Tags: scala

Suppose I've 2 case classes :

```
case class A (r: String) // with value "rr"
case class B (rr:String) // with value "ask"
```

how can I match the two so that

```
if(*value of case class B(A)* == *value of case class B.rr*) true
```

Is it possible in scala if yes then how?

I tried `A.getClass.getName.startsWith(B.rr)`

but got no output

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, please provide an example, even if it does not compile. Are you trying to check that `a.r == b.rr`?

Comment: Check it now if it helps @francoisr, Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What do you mean with `I tried A.getClass.getName.startsWith(B.rr) but got no output`? It is a boolean. You would get a console output by using `println(A.getClass.getName.startsWith(B.rr))`. Also it is still not clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to check whether `B.rr == "A"`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to check whether `B.rr` has some given class name as its values (and then the `r` member of `A` is irrelevant to this). Here is a solution in that case:

```scala
val b = new B("A")
b match {
    case B(classOf[A].getSimpleName) => // we know b.rr == "A"
    case _ => // b.rr != "A"
}
```

You can also just use `if (b.rr == classOf[A].getSimpleName) ... else ...`